# User env variable not working when PowerShell script started through Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, powershell, environment-variables

I have a VB.NET form which starts a PowerShell script. One of the parameters passed to this script is a password, which I don't want to be written to the Windows PowerShell log. That's why I use a user environment variable to temporarily store this password. This works fine, as long as I run the script *outside* of Visual Studio. When I start the same script through my VB application, the variable is empty. So it looks like the script started through my application somehow runs as a different user, but I don't understand why...
Even weirder: when I start my applications exe file from the debug directory, the user environment variable *does* work!
Does anybody have an idea where to look? Thanks for any help in advance!
Kind regards,
Eric van Loon

**Update 22-02-2023:**
Here's an example of the VB code I use:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TESTVAR", "Test Value", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)
        Process.Start("Powershell.exe", "-noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass c:\test\test.ps1")
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the code for c:\test\test.ps1:

```
Write-Output $env:TESTVAR
read-host "Press ENTER to continue..."
```

You will see that when you start the VB application for the very first time, the script will not show the value of TESTVAR:

```
Press ENTER to continue...:
```

If you close VS, restart it and rerun the same VB application, the script will now properly pick up the value of TESTVAR:

```
Test Value
Press ENTER to continue...:
```

So the environment variable set by `SetEnvironmentVariable()` is only available after a restart of VS. Same thing for the compiled executable by the way.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You forgot to post the code that sets the env variable as well as the code that executes PowerShell :)

Comment: By default, the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API  creates a child process that (a) runs with the same user identity and (b) with a copy of the caller's environment variables. Running with different user credentials and/or a modified environment requires explicit configuration.

Comment: Use

    [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name

or

    whoami

to get the current usercontext.

Comment: In the project properties you can find settings for debug parameters,  VS will start the app in debug with those params

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen, @mklement0, @Robin and @Hursey All thanks for your suggestions. I think I found the cause, now I just need to find the solution. When you use the `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()` to set an environment variable, it's *not* available for the running process itself. Only after restarting the process, the new variable is available. The problem is that the script which is started by my VB application, runs in the *same* environment as the VB application and thus can't find the variable. I don't know how you can (sort of) refresh the variables in the same environment...

Comment: @EricvanLoon Looks like you forgot to post your code again :)

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen You're absolutely right, sorry for the confusion. Code now added to my original question. Thanks again!